# Sitecore: Best practices for setting up Solr core for multisite

Tags: search, solr, sitecore, sitecore8

I understand that we can create N number of Cores in Solr. But I'm bit unclear on best practices for setting of Solr core for sitecore multisite implementation.
Scenario:
We have 5 sites in one sitecore instance. Each sites have search capability requirement.

Best practice questions:

1. Is it ok for each sites to share core and master index?
2. And, create a site specific cores for web index?
3. Do we need to setup the configuration file or similar in order to establish relationship between site(s) vs. solr core?

3.1. And I guess, each site needs to have sitecore solr index configuration file?
 e.g. Sitecore.ContentSearch.Solr.SiteA.Index.Web (copy of out of box index file which contains custom indexing name?)

4. Do we need to write any smartness (site context) such that search will use the correct solr Core?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer for this question is really opinion-based. There is no one solution which would be ideal in every situation.

There was even a discussion on [`https://sitecorechat.slack.com`](https://sitecorechat.slack.com) about it.

First of all you need to think whether you want to reuse any content between the sites. If yes, then you can use Sitecore out of the box indexes. You will not get that much from separate indexes. Of course you can create separate indexes but some of the content will have to be crawled multiple times.

If you want to create separate indexes:

1. Leave `sitecore_core_index`, `sitecore_master_index` and `sitecore_web_index` as they are - they will be used by Sitecore to run Content Editor search and other Sitecore background searches.
2. Create Solr `master` and `web` cores for every site, e.g. `site1_master_index` and `site1_web_index`.
3. For every site, duplicate the configuration for `sitecore_master_index` and `sitecore_web_index` and set proper locations of the content roots.

   E.g. create a copy of `Sitecore.ContentSearch.Solr.Index.Master.config` file (`Site1.ContentSearch.Solr.Index.Master.config`), and change its content to:

```xml
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <contentSearch>
      <configuration type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.ContentSearchConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
        <indexes hint="list:AddIndex">
          <index id="site1_master_index" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchIndex, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">
            <param desc="name">$(id)</param>
            <param desc="core">$(id)</param>
            <param desc="propertyStore" ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/databasePropertyStore" param1="$(id)" />
            <configuration ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/defaultSolrIndexConfiguration" />
            <strategies hint="list:AddStrategy">
              <strategy ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/indexUpdateStrategies/syncMaster" />
            </strategies>
            <locations hint="list:AddCrawler">
              <content type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SitecoreItemCrawler, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
                <Database>master</Database>
                <Root>/sitecore/content/site1</Root>
              </content>
              <media type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SitecoreItemCrawler, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
                <Database>master</Database>
                <Root>/sitecore/media library/site1</Root>
              </media>
            </locations>
          </index>
        </indexes>
      </configuration>
    </contentSearch>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

This configuration tells Sitecore to index only `/sitecore/content/site1` and `/sitecore/media library/site1` locations in this index.

4. Use convention to get proper index search, e.g.:

   ```
   ISearchIndex SearchIndex
   {
       get
       {
           return ContentSearchManager.GetIndex(Sitecore.Context.Site.Name + "_" + Sitecore.Context.Database.Name + "_index");
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Awesome answer, exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks heaps Marek.

Comment: Hi Marek, if we have 6 sitecore instances using Solr. Should all of them share the SAME core for core,web,master, etc? And create site specific custom indexes where necessary? Not sure what would be the performance impact if N number of instances share the same Cores.

Comment: Sitecore uses in background its default indexes (sitecore_core_index, sitecore_master_index, sitecore_web_index). I don't think you can change this behavior and I don't think there is any benefit in even trying.  Solr is capable of handling millions of documents. Yes, create site specific custom indexes where necessary.

Comment: What I meant was should we share ONE master, core, web for 6 instance of sitecore? Will there be any negative impact on performance etc?

Comment: Note of the 6 instances 3 of them are multisite with 2-3 sites each.

Comment: By 6 instances you mean 6 separate Sitecore applications? I think you need to have separate core for every installation. I never tried to reuse cores and I don't think it's possible. I suggest to contact with Sitecore Support but I don't think it's good idea - rebuilding index from one of the instances would clear items from the other instance.

Comment: Great answer, I was looking for this answer.